# How to extract/get all the terms(classes/properties) in an ontology

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

i have a data set of different ontologies and i want to extract/get all the classes, properties and any other thing that i can get out of ontology. Is there any method or library available for doing that as there are many ontologies and can't do it manually.
Later i need to store that all that data in an excel sheet.
Any help in that regard will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Library for what? OWL API, RDF4J, Jena, ... we don't know your ontologies ...   If it's just RDF, you can use SPARQL as well, for OWL you need a proper OWL parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a SPARQL endpoint such as Virtuoso Open Source Edition and upload the data from there:

1. Download and install [Virtuoso Open Source Edition](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/#How%20Do%20I%20Install%20Virtuoso%3F)
2. [import your RDF data into it](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert). For example, you can [download the DBpedia ontology](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2014/dbpedia_2014.owl.bz2), unpack it and upload `dbpedia_2014.owl` into a new graph in your SPARQL endpoint.
3. If you have configured graph security (should be disabled by default), give your user read rights to the graph. For example, to make the graph public, execute `DB.DBA.RDF_GRAPH_USER_PERMS_SET ('mygraph', 'nobody', 1);` as ISQL.

Now you can pose any kind of SPARQL query, such as:

A list of classes can be fetched with: `select * {?s a owl:Class.}` if they are explicitly modelled as such, `select * {{?s a owl:Class.} UNION {?s rdfs:subClassOf ?x.}}` otherwise.

Analogously, a list of properties can be queried with `select * {?s a rdf:Property.}`, respectively `select * {{?s a rdf:Property.} UNION {?s a owl:ObjectProperty.} UNION {?s a owl:DatatypeProperty.}}`.

If you just want a list of classes and properties, you can also use [Protégé](https://protege.stanford.edu/), which is much easier to set up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used protege but there are a lot of ontologies more than 500 and i cant manually go through all of them. i tried using owlready library for ontologies in python to extract class names, properties, annotation properties however  results are not good and for many ontologies it gives errors.
i want to extract the useful information of these ontologies to store it in a file and perform some natural language processing on that.

Comment: You are welcome! Please remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.